# PGP key issue while trying to install mysql2 in rails project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, windows, pgp, pacman-package-manager

I am trying to locally install all the gems for a rails project.

I have an issue with mysql2. When I try to install it, I have the following error:

```
Fetching mysql2-0.5.5.gem
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-x86_64-libmariadbclient
error: mingw32: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" could not be looked up remotely
error: mingw64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" could not be looked up remotely
error: msys: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" could not be looked up remotely
error: database 'mingw32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'mingw64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'msys' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
pacman failed with the following output:
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-lib="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include"'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I then tried to run `pacman -Syu`, but as well the same error, and I don't get asked to import the PGP key.

Thus, I tried to import the key manually, according to the one in the [MSI keyring GitHub](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-keyring/blob/master/msys2.gpg#L546) with  `pacman-key --add`. I then changed the trust to ultimate with `pacman-key --edit-key`.

But now, I have another error:

```
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-x86_64-libmariadbclient
error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/mingw32.db: Child process exited with status 127
error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/mingw64.db: Child process exited with status 127
error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/msys.db: Child process exited with status 127
error: target not found: mingw-w64-x86_64-libmariadbclient
pacman failed with the following output:
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-lib="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include"'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I don't know if I did wrong adding the key this way, or if the error comes from something else. I'm struggling on this for days now, I am kind of lost. Someone could help ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be something wrong with your installation of MSYS2 or pacman package manager. Child process exited with status 127 can indicate various issues.

Here are a few things we can try to resolve this error:

1. You can start by updating your MSYS2 installation with the following command:

```
pacman -Syu
```

2. If that doesn't work, we can try reinstalling MSYS2.
3. Another approach might be to remove the pacman cache and try again. You can do this with:

```
pacman -Scc
```

Noting the error is with mingw-w64-x86_64-libmariadbclient, you should confirm you have all the required dev packages installed.

```
sudo pacman -S mysql
```

There may also be a dev package. On Ubuntu it's "sudo apt install libmariadb-dev" or something similar, but I'm not sure for Arch Linux.